# A formula in complete lattice: $\bigwedge\{ a\vee b : a\in A , b\in B\}\leq (\bigwedge_{a\in A}a)\vee(\bigwedge_{b\in B}b) $

Tags: lattice-orders

Let $(\Gamma,\leq)$ be a complete lattice. Assume $A$ and $B$ are two subsets of $\Gamma$  with $a\wedge b=0$ for every $a\in A$ and $b\in B$.

Q. True or false:
 $$\bigwedge\{ a\vee b : a\in A , b\in B\}\leq (\bigwedge_{a\in A}a)\vee(\bigwedge_{b\in B}b) $$

Comment: Just the opposite, ∧{ a∨b : a∈A, b∈B } >= (∧a∈A a) ∨ (∧b∈B b) is true.

Comment: @amrsa.  Why is that a counter example?  Use  0 <= a,b,c,d <= 1 and A = {a,b}, B = {c,d}.

Comment: @WilliamElliot You're right. RHS = 1 too. I'll erase the comment soon. Thanks for warning.

Comment: My impression is that `\bigwedge` and `bigvee` ($\bigwedge$ and $\bigvee$) are more commonly used for suprema infima of set of elements. I have suggested the same edit also to your [post on MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/273541/an-inequality-in-complete-lattices). (Or course, if for some reason you prefer different notation, feel free to revert my edit.)

Comment: I have also removed (banach-lattices) tag since the question - at least the way it is stated now - is not about [Banach lattices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_lattice). (If you are specifically interested in vector lattices and Banach lattices, you should mention that in the question. If that's the case, then the tag should be used.)

Comment: @Martin Sleziak,  Thanks. Well done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated, the property is **false** in general: for example, let $\Gamma$ be the [diamond lattice $M_3$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_lattice#Characteristic_properties) with top element $1$, bottom element $0$, and middle elements $x,y,z$. Put $A=\{x,y\}$ and $B=\{z\}$. Then the LHS evaluates to $1$, but the RHS to $z$. **EDIT:** In response to the comments, we can slightly modify this example by inserting in the lattice an extra point $w$ such that $x,y<w<1$ (thus, $w=x\lor y$). The inequality still fails, while the additional hypotheses $\bigl(\bigvee A\bigr)\land\bigl(\bigvee B\bigr)=0$ and $\bigvee(A\cup B)=1$ hold. (Notice also that like $M_3$, the resulting lattice remains modular.)

On the other hand, the inequality is **true** if $\Gamma$ is distributive. First, if $A$ or $B$ is empty, then both sides evaluate to $1$, hence we may assume $A\ne\varnothing\ne B$. Fix $a_0\in A$, and $b_0\in B$. Let
$$c=\bigwedge_{\substack{a\in A\\b\in B}}(a\lor b)$$
denote the left-hand side. Using distributivity and the assumptions on $A$ and $B$, we have
$$\begin{align}
a_0\land c&=\bigwedge_{\substack{a\in A\\b\in B}}(a_0\land(a\lor b))\\
&=\bigwedge_{\substack{a\in A\\b\in B}}((a_0\land a)\lor(a_0\land b))\\
&=\bigwedge_{\substack{a\in A\\b\in B}}(a_0\land a)\\
&=\bigwedge_{a\in A}a,
\end{align}$$
and symmetrically,
$$b_0\land c=\bigwedge_{b\in B}b.$$
Thus, using distributivity again, we have
$$c=c\land(a_0\lor b_0)=(c\land a_0)\lor(c\land b_0)=\bigwedge_{a\in A}a\lor\bigwedge_{b\in B}b.$$

On the third hand, the property is **weaker** than distributivity. For example, let $\Gamma_1$ be an arbitrary complete lattice (in particular, non-distributive), and let $\Gamma$ be $\Gamma_1$ with a new least element $0$ attached. Then $\Gamma$ satisfies the property for the simple reason that the assumption $a\land b=0$ for all $a\in A$ and $b\in B$ holds only if one of the sets $A$, $B$ is $\varnothing$ or $\{0\}$, and the inequality is easy to verify in these cases.

Comment: What happned if we revise the question in this form: $(\Gamma,\leq)$ is a complete lattice, $A,B$ are subsets of $\Gamma$ with    $(\bigvee_{\substack{a\in A}}a)\bigwedge  (\bigvee_{\substack{b\in B}}b)=0$. Can we conclude the inequality proposed in the question?

Comment: Or with assumptions  $\bigvee \{x: x\in A\cup B\}=1$ and $(\bigvee\{a: a\in A\})\bigwedge (\bigvee\{b:b\in B\})=0$.